# How to run 2 websites and 2 different emails on one ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

Example: I have www.test1.com with my dns server(example.com) and I have another domain test2.com also on the same dns erver(example.com). What i am trying to achieve is when people go on test1.com it goes to /var/www/ but when people goto test2.com it goes to /var/www/test2/ when i update dns records on both of them pointing to my server they both goto /var/www/ I hope someone can answer my question

Comment: I am sure that google can help you with this.

Comment: What you are after is virtual hosts. I find Digital Ocean do really clean tutorials. Have a look at this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts